# In React, how do I pass input value to callback function?

Tags: redux, reactjs, react-redux

I'd like to call some callback in a React component whenever the input's value has changed.

simplified example should explain:

in a `jsx` file:

```
<input onKeyDown={this.props.changeCallback( VALUE_OF_INPUT )} ></input>
```

what should `VALUE_OF_INPUT` be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much React-specific about this. Use the `event` which is passed to the callback as the first argument:

```
onKeyDown={event => this.props.changeCallback(event.target.value)}
```

This approach (using a [fat arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions)) also handles binding `this`, at the expense of creating a new anonymous function once per render. Note that calling `bind` essentially does the same thing, so this is my preferred option out of the two.

It's important to make the distinction between assigning a function to the `onKeyDown` attribute (as is done here) and *calling* the function (what you did).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input value={this.state.value} onKeyDown={this.props.changeCallback.bind( this, this.state.value)} ></input>
```

Would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it dynamic is give it a value callback this works well if pre populating the "value" from some var.

```
/* Better function for larger forms */
handleChange = (event) =>  {
    var name = event.target.name;
    var value =  event.target.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
}
/* set Default and callback to state */
valueCallback = (value, name) => {
    if (this.state[name]) {
        return this.state[name]
    }
    else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

then you can go ...

```
 var defaut = '1234'; // or this.props.something.something;

 <input type={type} name={name} value={this.valueCallback(defaut, name)}  onChange={this.handleChange} />
```